# PyQt5: Object has no attribute 'exec_' with two main windows

Tags: python, pyqt, exec, qt-designer, pyuic

I am new to PyQt, so when I am creating UI files, I just copied one Mainwindow (mainfile.ui) and changed it to produce another UI file (Intro.ui). I know this is not a good way to create UI files,
as it always gives the error: `object has no attribute 'exec_'`.

Here is the code:

```
MainFile = "mainfile.ui"

Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(MainFile)

FileIntro = "Intro.ui" 

Ui_WindowIntro,_ = uic.loadUiType(FileIntro)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.ButtonIntro.clicked.connect(self.OpenWindowIntro)
    def OpenWindowIntro(self):
        s = WindowIntro()
        s.show()
        s.exec_() #here is the problem.

class WindowIntro(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_WindowIntro):

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_WindowIntro.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        #close the window
        self.Button2.clicked.connect(self.Close)

    def Close(self):
        self.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = 0 # if not the core will die

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    if login():

        window = MainWindow()

        window.show()

        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem. Once the python console shows this `AttributeError`, the kernel will die.

Comment: Besides, if I don't write the line s.exec_(), the window will not show.However,if I run it in Ipython Console, the kernel will not die

Comment: remove s.exec() and inside WindowIntro __init__: self.widget = QWidget() then self.widget.show()

Comment: Thank you very much, that works!

Comment: Nice, I'll post an answer then

Comment: @NewBieBR actually, i solved it by deleting exec(), and replace it with: self.anotherwindow = windowIntro().  Self.anotherwindow.show(). And this works.

Comment: There can be only one exec()

Comment: hmm. So the first WindowIntro() show() doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, if you don’t add exec() after show(), the windowIntro will not show after the click in the Mainwindow. But using exec(), the Kennel will show an error : object has no attributes exec(), and the kernel will die. This is controversial. I compiled it to exe, and the program will close as soon as I open it.  As I have mentioned, exec() is an attribute of the mainwindow. So to solve this problem, I just used the aforementioned methods.

Answer (score 6):

This one works fine,thanks for all you help:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets

MainFile = "mainfile.ui"
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(MainFile)
FileIntro = "Intro.ui" 
Ui_WindowIntro,_ = uic.loadUiType(FileIntro)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.ButtonIntro.clicked.connect(self.OpenWindowIntro)

    def OpenWindowIntro(self):
        self.anotherwindow = WindowIntro()
        self.anotherwindow.show()

class WindowIntro(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_WindowIntro):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_WindowIntro.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        #close the window
        self.Button2.clicked.connect(self.Close)

    def Close(self):
        self.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = 0 # if not the core will die
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    if login():
        window = MainWindow()
        window.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```